# How to check if a specific kind of file exists in folder with shell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Here's a simple script I use to clean up torrent downloads for my tv shows:

```
find . ! -path . -type d -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3 -exec sh -c '
dir="$0"
tvnamer --batch $dir
mv $dir/*.mkv $dir/..
trash $dir
' {} ';'
```

How can I modify it with if statement to check if $dir has any .part files in it? I obviously only want the `trash $dir` part to happen when there's no .part files :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `test` operator:

```
[ -f $dir/*.part ] || trash $dir
```

(instead of saying: `trash $dir`)

Saying so would execute `trash $dir` only if the directory contains `.part` files.

---

Alternatively, you could say:

```
[[ "$(ls $dir/*.part)" =~ \.part$ ]] 2>/dev/null || trash $dir
```

Comment: will this work if there are multiple `.part` files in `${dir}`?

Comment: @umläute What's your guess?

Comment: my guess is *no, it won't work*; e.g. having two `.part`-files will yield *[: FOO/BAR.part: binary operator expected*

Comment: @umläute Good guess.  In this case, the issue wouldn't arise as there would be one .part file and others like .part.00x.

Comment: so it only works because you have a-priori knowledge that whoever creates the `.part` files will only ever create a single one. i guess it would be good to point that out in the answer (esp. since the OP asked for a solution that checks "if $dir has *any* .part *files*" in it

Comment: @umläute Updated; but I guess you've added a pretty similar answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

if you need a solution that checks whether there are one *or more* files matching a given pattern, you might have more luck using:

```
ls "${dir}"/*.part >/dev/null 2>&1 || trash "${dir}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `test(1)` and `&&` operator. For example:
Change
    `trash $dir
to`
    `[ ! -e $dir/*.part ] && trash $dir`
which is the same as

```
if [ ! -e $dir/*.part ]; then
  trash $dir
fi
```

where `[ ! -e $dir/*.part ]` is calling of `test(1)` in following way: 'Test whether there doesn't (`!`) exist (`-e`) file ending in `.part` in `$dir`. If such file doesn't exist, this succeeds and therefore the trash part is called.